# Scrape Webpages at regular intervals automatically with python

Tags: python, email, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I monthly scrape a website for products' prices and send an email if there are any changes in the prices?
Is there's any way to do that automatically using Python? What libraries should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use crontab or airflow and set your scraper to run every month.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Do you know about the part of automatically sending emails based on conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use job queues to do this and in the simplest way, you can use [`RQ`](https://python-rq.org/).

```py
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from datetime import timedelta

scrap_queue = Queue(connection=Redis())

def scrap_some_data():
    ... # my scraper code in here
def main():
    scrap_queue.enqueue_in(timedelta(minutes=30), scrap_some_data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`scrap some data` function will call every 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks so much. It really helps.